# Error returned when trying to delete field with ajax in dialog box jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-dialog

I have list of surveys, each of them have edit button, when clicked, the button dialog box pops up with their answers from database, those answers have delete button with them, but I can't make them to work. This is my code. 
**JQUERY:**

```
 $( "#dialog1" ).dialog({ 
    autoOpen: false,
    width:'auto',

   open: function(event, ui){
       $('<button>', {
            'class': 'button'
        })
        .appendTo($(".wrapper"))
        .click(function(){

            var prom=$(this).closest('div').attr('id') ;
            alert(prom);
          $.ajax({
                url: 'admin/deleteField',
                type: 'post',
                data: { idanswer: prom} ,
                success: function () {
                alert("success");

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");

                }
            });
        });
});
```

**PHP**

```
    public function deleteField()
{

    $IdAnswer=(int)$_POST['idanswer']; 

    Answer::DeleteAnswer($IdAnswer);

}
```

**HTML**

```
    <?php
    $answers=$survey->AllAnswers;
    foreach($answers as $answ)
    {
?>
<div class="wrapper" id="<?php echo $answ['Id']; ?>" style="width:auto;">
<input id='answers' name='answers[]' type='text' value='<?php echo $answ['Answer']; ?>'>    
<?php } ?>
```

When I clicked on delete button of some answer, alert("error") shows up for a second and then dialog box closes and nothing happens.

Comment: `Answer::DeleteAnswer(IdAnswer);`  should be `Answer::DeleteAnswer($IdAnswer);`

Comment: Oh, that's a typo, I just edit it! But that's not it, in my code that is correct. tnx!

Comment: I think you should check your url

Comment: url is definitely fine, I checked it, tnx!

Comment: ok, so I just added `return false;` at the end of the ajax call and it's working!! Don't know why exactly but great, tnx @Awlad Liton and @sayali for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

ok, so I just added return false; at the end of the ajax call and it's working!

```
 $( "#dialog1" ).dialog({ 
autoOpen: false,
width:'auto',

open: function(event, ui){
   $('<button>', {
        'class': 'button'
    })
    .appendTo($(".wrapper"))
    .click(function(){

        var prom=$(this).closest('div').attr('id') ;
        alert(prom);
      $.ajax({
            url: 'admin/deleteField',
            type: 'post',
            data: { idanswer: prom} ,
            success: function () {
            alert("success");

            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");

            }
        });
return false;
    });
});
```